# How to use same grunt task with different options/arguments?

Tags: git, gruntjs

I am using the grunt-git plugin found here: https://github.com/rubenv/grunt-git. The plugin defines some tasks like gitpush and gitpull among others. Here is an example of the gitpush task:

```
 grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    //grunt-git tasks 
    gitpush: {
        task: {
          options: {
              remote: 'origin',
              branch: 'cojo',
        }
      }
    },
```

The branch option is required. Its default value is null, i.e. I can leave it blank because it will not push to the current branch I am on, it will just not push at all. Sometimes I want to use it to push to the "master" branch instead of the "cojo" branch. What I can't figure out (I am new to Grunt) is how to create the gitpush task again, under a different name, in order to give it the option to push to the master. In my head I picture what I want like this:

```
 gitpush: {
        task: {
          options: {
              remote: 'origin',
              branch: 'cojo',
        }
      }
    },

 gitpush2: {
        task: {
          options: {
              remote: 'origin',
              branch: 'master',
        }
      }
    },
```

This obviously doesn't work yet because gitpush is the name of the task defined by the grunt-git plugin. Another option I thought of was creating an alias task and passing an argument to it, but I don't know if this would be possible or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use different targets.

```
gitpush: {
  cojo: {
    options: {
      remote: 'origin',
      branch: 'cojo',
    }
  },
  master: {
    options: {
      remote: 'origin',
      branch: 'master',
    }
  }
}
```

Run these using gitpush:cojo or gitpush:master as needed.